# Java WildCards - Simple Producer Consumer

Tags: java, generics

I am currently implementing a problem that requires using Wildcards, and creating a very simple producer/consumer class using them. The problem is given below, and uses a List of generic type T. I am confused on where to even start on this problem. I am quite unfamiliar with Wildcards, and would love any help or hints y'all could provide to steer me in the right direction! I have included the problem below.

Wildcards. Below is a `Shop<T>` class that maintains a stock of
objects of type `T`. There are two sell functions: one for selling a single item of type `T` and another for selling all items in a `List<T>`. There are two buy methods: one to buy a single item of type `T` and the other to buy n items at a time, to be added into a `List<T>` collection provided as an argument to the buy function.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Shop<T> {
    List<T> stock;

    public Shop() { 
        stock = new LinkedList<T>(); 
    }

    public T buy() {
        return stock.remove(0);
    }

    void sell(T item) {
        stock.add(item);
    }

    void buy(int n, List<T> items) {
        for (T e : stock.subList(0, n)) {
            items.add(e);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) stock.remove(0);
    }

    void sell(List<T> items) {
        for (T e : items) {
           stock.add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see [`List.addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) for adding collections to a list

Comment: Honestly this is the laziest question I've seen on SO. No attempt to conceal the fact that it's homework and no attempt to explain what problem you're having. I award you no points, and may God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Sorry KyleM, this was only one of 3 questions on this assignment, and this is the only one I really had no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you're being asked to modify the signatures `void buy(int n, List<T> itmes)` and `void sell(List<T> items)` to allow better flexibility on types.

First, you're being asked to allow any collection to be used. For this task, *it is enough if you change both signatures to accept `Collection` instead of `List`*.

The second part is where wildcards are involved. Let's see first the problem:

Suppose we instantiate a `Shop<Dog>` and want to buy some dogs.

```
Shop<Dog> dogShop = ...
List<Animal> myAnimals = ...
dogShop.buy(3, myAnimals); // **TYPE ERROR**
```

This happens because in `buy` we are asking for a `Collection<Dog>` *exactly*. Instead, this should be the signature:

```
void buy(int n, Collection<? super T>) { /*...*/ }
```

This allows us to pass a collection *of any supertype of `T`*. In our example, you could pass a `List<Animal>`, as `Animal` is a superclass of `Dog`.

Out next problem is `sell`. Similarly, we could *not* do the following:

```
Shop<Animal> animalShop = ...
Set<Cat> myCats = ...
animalShop.sell(myCats); // **TYPE ERROR**
```

Again, we're asking for a `Collection<Animal>` exactly, so we can't pass a set of `Cat`s. Instead, you'd write its signature as:

```
void sell(Collection<? extends T> items) { /* ... */ }
```

This will accept any collection *of any subtype of `T`*. In our example, a `Set<Cat>` works, as `Cat` is a subtype of `Animal`

For more details and a full explanation, visit the [official documentation on Generic Type Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: Thanks Darkhogg! I'm new to Java Collections, so this is a great start.